# Get WPF Name of shape at MouseDown Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control with 7 shapes into it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Gramas.OdontogramaUI.PiezaUI"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="280" Width="238.429" Name="EstaPieza" Margin="0,2" Loaded="EstaPieza_Loaded">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Partes" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.457">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="31*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="45*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="87*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="44*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="31*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="53"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="36*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="74*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="52*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Viewbox Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
            <Grid Name="ContenedorPieza" Height="299.814" Width="238.429">
                <Path x:Name="Shape1" Data=""/>
                <Path x:Name="Shape2" Data=""/>
                <Path x:Name="Shape3" Data=""/>
                <Path x:Name="Shape4" Data=""/>
                <Path x:Name="Shape5" Data=""/>
                <Path x:Name="Shape6" Data=""/>
                <Path x:Name="Shape7" Data=""/>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="NombrePieza" Text="{Binding ElementName=Esta_Pieza,Path=Pieza.Id}" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Panel.ZIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HotTrackBrushKey}}" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Each shape is named using `x:Shape1`, I' want to control `mousedown event` into a single method

```
Shape1.MouseDown += Superficie_MouseDown;
Shape2.MouseDown += Superficie_MouseDown;
. . .

private void Superficie_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //some stuff here;
}
```

My problem is I Can't Access the Name of the sender in my code behind, how can I do to identify the sender ? must handle it in separate methods.... one for each shape ?

Comment: Could you define your own shapes by inheriting and adding a getName() funtion. this way you can cast/[as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) to your class from sender and call your function.

Comment: Your mouse down event has sender.

Comment: mmmm  very ugly thing, since my shapes allready has a name.

Comment: @Sampath Yes it has it. My question is about how to get the  ``sender`` name

Comment: Cast your sender to Path object @ your event handler and then you can get its name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecast sender to shape and access Name property of shape:

```
private void Superficie_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    string name = ((Shape)sender).Name;
}
```

Comment: or `string name = (sender as Shape).Name;`

Comment: I see no issue in direct casting though.

Comment: @Rohit Vats Very tks, do you know why ``(Shape)sender`` doesn't work ?

Comment: You need to wrap sender in parenthesis to get Shape object and access its property. The way you mentioned will still be of type `object` and no Name property exist in object.

Comment: You are right, only difference is that `as` does not cause an exception.

Comment: @user2754599 - No, it will throw exception since you are trying to access property after typecasting, in case sender is not Shape.

Comment: @Rohit Vats [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape(v=vs.110).aspx) does have a name property

Comment: @RohitVats Very tks for your help. It Works pretty well. I'm forgetting the ``parenthesis``.